# How do I animate text inside a UI Label?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am a beginner using 'x-code swift'.

I want the text in 'Label' to move slowly from right to left. I want to make it move like the characters on the news screen.

[image: I want to code like this animation.]

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you haven't tried anything. Try a `UILabel` in a `UIScrollView` which helps the user scroll it. If it is just a static animation, then it's just a `UILabel` in a `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn’t need to be animated fluently you could move the string every half a second or whatever forward.

So you have a buffer string and an original string and change the buffer string/the UI Label every half a second by one character from the original string. To repeat this action every 1 second or so you can use the Timer() class